# Single cell or multiple cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working on an iOS project, writing in Swift. It's a social network app where people have profiles and they can post different type of content. There should be 9 type of posts/content:

- Normal (text only) post
- Images post
- Gif post
- Video post
- Audio post
- Quote post
- Chat post
- Poll post
- Link post

My question is related to how should I display it on the feed. The feed obviously would be some type of a collection (I think I'll stick with `UICollectionView`) but should I create 1 type of a cell, add every single element that I might need to display each type of a content embedded into a `UIStackView` and if it's the database request returns `nil` for an object (i.e that particular post doesn't have video or an audio, a poll, etc - all it contains is just some images) then I'll hide those `UIStackViews` from the cell OR should I create a separate type of a cell and its xib file, depending on the the content type?

I feel like the latter would be easier, but I'm not how to that? Meaning, how should I check what type of a content is it? Imagine something like Twitter for example, you see many different type of content, how should you approach the cell creation and displaying them?

PS: Keep in mind that the users should be able to filter their content based on the content type (i.e display only images, only text, only audio, etc). How should I approach this?

Comment: "Meaning, how should I check what type of a content is it?" It's up to your "model" (post) to know that.

Comment: I presume the actual _model_ will define the _cell-identifier_ what defines the prototype cell's visual appearance – I don't clearly understand your problem here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, it is better to create separate cell for every content type and manipulate views in it as needed. It is clearer and simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Better option is create the different cell for different posts/content, and use the model classes variable/enum for know which type of content is it. its easy for filtering and managing the all type of posts.